# R:Error while loading Hmisc and psych

Tags: r, hmisc

I received 2 errors while trying to library Hmisc and psych:

1)

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'grid', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: object 'L_initGrid' not found
In addition: There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘psych’
```

2)

```
Loading required package: lattice
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'grid', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: object 'L_initGrid' not found
In addition: There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Error: package ‘lattice’ could not be loaded
```

I have both packages installed on my R 3-4.1 version.

Could you suggest how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the packages? Can you load lattice and grid with `library`?

Comment: I tried and lattice is in library folder now. Grid seems to be in the base package, I can't download it directly.

Comment: I would try this `remove.packages(c("Hmisc", "psych"))
install.packages('Hmisc', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('psych', dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: OK. From your last comment I infer that you do not know how to install packages in R. Please use `install.packages` for installing.

Comment: No, after install.packages() I use library(), and errors appeared on that stage.
Finally, I resolved the issues by replacing R 64-bit by R 32-bit. Now everything works well. Thank you for your comments!